# Pull to refresh doesn't show text or picture in tableview

Tags: ios, tableview, pull-to-refresh

I imported https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh to my project. It works as in: I can pull down my tableview and it refreshes itself. Thing is that I don't get any text or the arrow while refreshing. I tried importing and subclassing it (works, BUT no text or arrow). And I implemented it directly into my class (Still works, but no text or arrow). Hope someone has a solution.

Here is how I call it in my class:

In my .h file I import it

```
#import "PullRefreshTableViewController.h"
```

and also subclass it

```
@interface Friends : PullRefreshTableViewController
```

In my .m file I do as told and add:

```
-(void)refresh {

[self performSelector:@selector(doXMLParsing) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];}
```

and put

```
[self stopLoading];
```

at the end of my method.

It does what it supposed to do, sadly without showing text or the arrow.

Comment: Did you link against the QuartzCore framework ?

Comment: Hm and the demo project that is included, does that work?

Comment: Yes, works fine. Someone else also had the problem and posted it in github issues and it got solved by inialitizing the strings in the viewDidLoad. Sadly that didn't work for me.

Comment: Strings are set in the ``setupStrings`` method. The label and arrow are added as subviews in the ``addPullToRefreshHeader`` method. Are these methods called?

Comment: Yes. I also implemented them in the viewDidLoad just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to simply apply pull to refresh in tableView.

Declare refreshControl in header file of your view Controller as:-

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
```

and use in implementation file as:-

```
refreshControl=[[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.tintColor=t.tableCellSelectionColor;
[refreshControl setAttributedTitle:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refresh Title"]];//Optional

[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[tblView addSubview:refreshControl];

-(void)reloadTable
{
    // do your stuff here....
    [tblView reloadData];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```